# How to change the price or currency switcher on home page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency

I'm trying to change the product price on home page which is called from static block, In that price is not changed when we changed the price in home page but in list page and pdp page price showing on selected currency.

Before I wrote I also add a cahe_lifetime but not worked properly.

```
<div id="mostLoved">{{block type="bestseller/bestsellers" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml" cache_lifetime="1" }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you're price output isn't using currency switcher. The price for use rates and currencies must be wrapped by:

```
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```

Manual: 
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-format-price/